# What are some sources against treating others possessions with respect

Tags: halacha, torah-study, torts-damages, mishpatim, bava-batra

BH

What are the sources of treating other peoples property carefully and not devaluing it’s value like saying “because it’s not so expensive it must not be so valuable there for if it breaks its still not as expensive as something else”

Comment: Consider chullin 91a https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.91a.22